# How to rewrite VBO results?

Tags: views

In the 'Rewrite Results' section of the 'Configure Field' popup, there are several options to rewrite the results - but not in the way I need.  I want to substitute particular strings in the output.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

For string changes your best bet is altering the view in a custom module. Use  [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7.x-3.x) to modify the output of the fields prior to the view result being fully outputted.